# Descendent of a child process not receiving SIGTERM on ubuntu but receives on mac

Tags: node.js, jestjs, webpack-dev-server, child-process, sigterm

So I have some code which runs a command in a spawned child process. I do this using the [execa](https://github.com/sindresorhus/execa) module.

```js
      const childProcess = execa.command('yarn start');
      const localhostStarted = await waitForLocalhost({ port: 8000 });
      expect(localhostStarted.done).toBe(true);
      childProcess.kill('SIGINT', { forceKillAfterTimeout: 2000 });
```

The `yarn start` command executes `webpack-dev-server` in another child process of its own. However when I kill the `childProcess` that I spawned, it does not automatically kill its spawned `webpack-dev-server` process. It is known to be an issue here https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2168.

To fix this I add manual listeners for `SIGINT` & `SIGTERM` inside my script which runs when `yarn start` is called

```js
    ['SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'].forEach((signal) => {
      console.log('registering events');
      process.on(signal, () => {
        console.log('received signal', signal);
        devServer.close(() => {
          console.log('exiting proces');
          process.exit(0);
        });
      });
    });
```

This fixes the issue on my local machine and when I kill child process I spawn, it kills all its descendents i.e the dev-server process too.

However, this fix still does not work on CI, and since the child process gets killed on CI but not the dev-server process, my tests dont exit and keeps hanging.

My local machine is `OSX 10.15` but on CI we use `ubuntu`. If I change CI to use `macos 10.15`, then the fix works on CI too.

I am unable to find any docs on this issue which explains the different behaviour on why the signal of `SIGTERM` is not received by the `dev-server` process on ubuntu machines but receives fine on mac machines.